# Unsupported Segment Type returned on GraphAPI callRecords

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an active GraphAPI subscription to /communications/callRecords which is successfully returning the callid for calls.  When attempting to get the call details using the following request:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/45578cfe-8329-48b7-ba6b-54a627b00bf4?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)

I receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: /communications/callRecords/45578cfe-8329-48b7-ba6b-54a627b00bf4",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-24T12:34:11",
            "request-id": "277b4fa1-11a5-4922-94d7-83fec3a57572",
            "client-request-id": "277b4fa1-11a5-4922-94d7-83fec3a57572"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same error if I change the GraphAPI call to /v1.0/.  I am sure this worked previously but can't seem to work out what may have changed.

Comment: (1) Does the subscription is active? (2) Can you repro the issue without the odata filters as well?

Comment: (1) Yes, the subscription is active (2) I can reproduce the issue with and without the odata filters

Comment: Please try to debug by setting ngrok and see what you notice in it. If issue persists, then you can consider checking with Microsoft support to see what went wrong.

Comment: Checkout this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter) for syntax and try Once again.

Comment: @PeterHawes- Are you still facing this issue?